# How to make a select with Ionic 5 and Vue.js

Tags: typescript, vue.js, ionic-framework

I have a problem getting the value of an Ion-select element using Vue.JS Framework. I am very new to both Ionic and Vue.JS so  sorry if I missed something obvious :)

My page.vue

```
<template>
  <ion-page>
    <ion-header>
      <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-title color="primary">Takeoff</ion-title>
      </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>
    <ion-content :fullscreen="true">
      <ion-header collapse="condense">
        <ion-toolbar>
          <ion-title size="large">Takeoff</ion-title>
        </ion-toolbar>
      </ion-header>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Toogle Dark Mode</ion-label>
        <ion-toggle id="themeToggle"></ion-toggle>
      </ion-item>
      <Airport label="" v-model="Airport.ICAO" type="text"></Airport>
      <RwyCondition
        :options="Runway_conditions"
        v-model="Runway.surface"
        type="text"
        label="Set runway condition: "
      ></RwyCondition>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Wind direction°</ion-label>
        <ion-input placeholder="xxx°"></ion-input>
        <ion-label>Wind component</ion-label>
        <ion-input placeholder="wind kts"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Outside air temperature (OAT)</ion-label>
        <ion-input placeholder="xx°"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>QNH</ion-label>
        <ion-input placeholder="1013 hPa"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Trust derate</ion-label>
        <ion-select placeholder="Optimum">
          <ion-select-option value="Optimum">Optimum</ion-select-option>
          <ion-select-option value="26K">26K</ion-select-option>
          <ion-select-option value="24K">24K</ion-select-option>
          <ion-select-option value="22K">22K</ion-select-option>
          <ion-select-option value="Windshare">Windshare</ion-select-option>
        </ion-select>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>ATM</ion-label>
        <ion-input placeholder=""></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Flaps setting</ion-label>
        <ion-select placeholder="5">
          <ion-select-option value="1">1</ion-select-option>
          <ion-select-option value="5">5</ion-select-option>
          <ion-select-option value="10">10</ion-select-option>
          <ion-select-option value="15">15</ion-select-option>
          <ion-select-option value="25">25</ion-select-option>
        </ion-select>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Air Conditionning</ion-label>
        <ion-select placeholder="AUTO">
          <ion-select-option value="AUTO">AUTO</ion-select-option>
          <ion-select-option value="OFF">OFF</ion-select-option>
        </ion-select>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Air Conditionning</ion-label>
        <ion-select placeholder="AUTO">
          <ion-select-option value="AUTO">AUTO</ion-select-option>
          <ion-select-option value="OFF">OFF</ion-select-option>
        </ion-select>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Anti-ice</ion-label>
        <ion-select placeholder="OFF">
          <ion-select-option value="OFF">OFF</ion-select-option>
          <ion-select-option value="Engines">Engines</ion-select-option>
          <ion-select-option value="Engines + Wings"
            >Engines + Wings</ion-select-option
          >
        </ion-select>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Takeoff weight</ion-label>
        <ion-input placeholder="XXX kgs"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Center of gravity</ion-label>
        <ion-input placeholder="25%"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <p>
        <ion-button size="large" shape="round" @click="compute()">
          <ion-icon slot="end" :icon="airplane"></ion-icon>
          Compute
        </ion-button>
      </p>
      <br />
      <p>
        Export to JSON: <br />
        {{ Airport.ICAO }} <br />
        {{ Runway.surface }} <br />
      </p>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-page>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import {
  IonPage,
  IonHeader,
  IonToolbar,
  IonTitle,
  IonContent,
  IonButton,
  IonIcon,
  IonSelect,
  IonSelectOption,
  IonLabel,
  IonInput,
} from "@ionic/vue";
import { airplane } from "ionicons/icons";
import Airport from "@/components/Airport.vue";
import RwyCondition from "@/components/RwyCondition.vue";

export default {
  name: "Takeoff",
  components: {
    IonHeader,
    IonToolbar,
    IonTitle,
    IonContent,
    IonPage,
    IonButton,
    IonIcon,
    IonSelect,
    IonSelectOption,
    IonLabel,
    IonInput,
    Airport,
    RwyCondition,
  },
  setup() {
    return {
      airplane,
    };
  },

  methods: {
    Test() {
      console.log("Value changed!");
    },

    compute() {
      console.log("Test compute! ");
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      Airport: {
        ICAO: "",
      },
      Runway_conditions: ["dry", "wet", "medium"],
      Flaps_take_off_settings: [1, 5, 10, 15, 20],
      Runway: {
        surface: "",
      },
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

And the component code:

```
<template>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label v-if="label">{{ label }}</ion-label>
    <ion-select
      @ionChange="updateRwyCondition"
      placeholder="Select a condition:"
    >
      <ion-select-option
        placeholder="Select runway condition:"
        v-for="option in options"
        :value="option"
        :key="option"
      >
        {{ option }}
      </ion-select-option>
    </ion-select>
  </ion-item>
</template>

<script>
import { IonItem, IonLabel, IonSelect, IonSelectOption } from "@ionic/vue";
import { defineComponent } from "vue";
export default defineComponent({
  components: { IonItem, IonLabel, IonSelect, IonSelectOption },
  props: {
    label: {
      type: String,
      default: "",
    },
    modelValue: {
      type: [String, Number],
      default: "",
    },
    options: {
      type: Array,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  methods: {
    // Does work!
    updateRwyCondition(event) {
      console.log(event.detail.value);
    },
  },
});
</script>
```

My ending goal is to create a JSON file with all the value of the form exported. But as a first step I want to have all the values shown on the page.

Best regards,
Damien

Answer (score 0):

Add `v-model` to ion-select

```
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Trust derate</ion-label>
        <ion-select placeholder="Optimum" v-model="Trust-derate-value">
          <ion-select-option value="Optimum">Optimum</ion-select-option>
          <ion-select-option value="26K">26K</ion-select-option>
          <ion-select-option value="24K">24K</ion-select-option>
          <ion-select-option value="22K">22K</ion-select-option>
          <ion-select-option value="Windshare">Windshare</ion-select-option>
        </ion-select>
      </ion-item>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I should have been more specific in asking my question and have posted a minimal working code.

The problem is with the runway condition component. It works if I use Vue.js components. However, if I use Ionic component, I cannot output the value on the page using
 ` {{ Runway.surface }} <br />`

Comment: I still don't understand... because this worked for me using ionic components.